# Need to Assign Value of Bootstrap Dropdown in Angular UI-Grid to Row.Entity

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I need to use a Bootstrap dropdown-menu in my ui-grid cellTemplate, and capture the selection in order to show their selection on the button.  The problem is that because I can't use `ng-model` on a `<li>`, when I capture the selection, all of the dropdowns in the grid are updated with the selection text.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4q8zEAMvEElW24iJSCDC?p=preview) demonstrating my issue.

Here is my Controller code:

```
    $scope.actions = [

  { id: 'action1', name: 'Action 1' },
  { id: 'action2', name: 'Action 2' }
    ];
    $scope.selectedAction = { id: 'action0', name: 'SelectOne' };
    $scope.setAction = function (action) {
        $scope.selectedAction = action;
        $scope.submitAction();
    };
    $scope.submitAction = function () {
        console.log($scope.selectedAction.id);
    };
  $scope.gridOptions = { rowHeight: 38 };

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'id', enableCellEdit: false },
    { name: 'name', displayName: 'Name (editable)' },
    { name: 'age', displayName: 'Age' , type: 'number' },
    {
                      field: 'Action', displayName: 'Action',                
                cellClass: 'center',
      cellTemplate: 'myDropDown.html',
      enableSorting: false
    }
  ];

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
  <div class="btn-group" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-click="grid.appScoe.submitAction()">
      {{grid.appScope.selectedAction.name}}<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:230px"><li ng-repeat="action in grid.appScope.actions"><span ng-click="grid.appScope.setAction(action)">{{action.name}}</span></li></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're binding the selection to a single scope variable when you need to bind it to a model per grid row.  Your model needs a column called Action to correspond with your grid config

Comment: I realize that, but as my question states, since I can't put a model on <li>, how do I bind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked your plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xogVhKiSrxXEHiPO9275?p=preview)

You're binding the selection to a single scope variable when you need to bind it to a model per grid row. Your model needs a column called Action to correspond with your grid config.   For the sake of the example I simply added a column:

```
$http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/500_complex.json')
.success(function(data) {
  data.map(function(element) {
    element.Action = $scope.selectedAction;
  });
  $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
});
```

I modified setAction() to pass in the row and the selected action:

```
$scope.setAction = function(row, action) {
   row.entity.Action = action;
   $scope.submitAction();
};
```

And changed your cell template to work with the controller changes:

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
   <div class="btn-group" dropdown dropdown-append-to-body>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-click="grid.appScoe.submitAction()">
        {{row.entity.Action.name}}<span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:230px"><li ng-repeat="action in grid.appScope.actions"><span ng-click="grid.appScope.setAction(row, action)">{{action.name}}</span></li></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I figured I was missing something simple.